# SAPUI5 - GET request

Tags: sapui5

How can I display a JSON data using an url in SAPUI5.
I use SAPUI5 for frontend dev.

This is my controller function:

```
initThingsModel:function () {

    var oMenuModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();

    oMenuModel.loadData("http://localhost:8085/things"); 

    sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oMenuModel);
}
```

But I don't know how should my view.xml look.

Comment: "I don't know how should my view.xml look" Where exactly are you stuck? How is your app structured? Please, show us more code.

Answer (score 1):

You can access your properties by using "{yourPropertyNameHere}"

Answer (score 1):

Simple example :

### 1. External JSON File (jsonfilename.json)

```
{
  "first":"India", 
  "second":"Singapore", 
  "third":"Malaysia"
}
```

### 2. In Controller

```
onInit: function() { 
  var oModel = new JSONModel();
  oModel.loadData("jsonfilename.json"); // jsonfilename.json is in root
  this.getView().setModel(oModel);
},
```

### 3. In XML View

```
<Text text="{/first}" />
<Text text="{/second}" />
<Text text="{/third}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
oMenuModel.attachRequestCompleted(function() {
    var data = oMenuModel.getData();
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: How does this help the asker?

Answer (score 0):

**Json File:- data.json**

```
{
"name": [{
    "fnm": "abc",
    "lnm": "xyz",
    "city": "PQR"
}]
}
```

**Controller.js**

```
var oModel = sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel("model/data.json");
this.getView().setModel(oModel);
```

**View.xml**

```
<Table id = "idtbl" items ="{/name}">
<columns>
    <Column>
          <Text text = "First Name">
    </Column>
      <Column>
          <Text text = "Last Name">
    </Column>
     <Column>
          <Text text = "City">
     </Column>
</columns>
<items>
    <columnListItem>
           <cells>
                  <Text text = "{fnm}"/>
                  <Text text = "{lnm}"/>
                  <Text text = "{city}"/>
         </cells>
    </columnListItem>
 </items>
</Table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Odata service then you have to pass parameter as follows

```
/things?$format=json
```

if you are using open rest api then you have to pass content type in headers as follows

```
Content-type: application/json
```

Answer (score 0):

EDITED

This piece of code should help you to pass data from controller side into view:

```
initThingsModel:function () {
    // create JSONModel
    var oMenuModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
    // loadData returns Promise
    oMenuModel.loadData("http://localhost:8085/things");
    // set data to JSONMode and your view
    this.getView().setModel(oMenuModel, "dataModel");
}
```

Then you can display your data in XML view like following:

```
<Text text="{dataModel>/property}" />
```

Another question could be, does your service or backend support oData protocol? If yes, then I would recommend to use *sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel* for a communication with backend. If your backend does not have oData support then I would recommend to create backend requests using *XMLHttpRequest* object and once you retrieve a data from a backend, you just call *setData* method of you *JSONModel*.

Comment: JSONModel already performs `setData` if `loadData` succeeds: https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/ca0c1dfbe2f71c1f422fb9d37ebc43a19c385617/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel.js#L212. I.e. handling the promise is not required. Question author needs to provide more code to know what the actual problem is